# Azure Website publish doesn't work since Azure Outage 'ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, web, publish

The past months, I've used 'Web Publish' from Visual Studio to **publish my project to an Azure Website**. This worked fine...until this morning, just right after the big Azure outage...

Since this morning I receive the following error whenever I try to publish to my Azure Website (Western Europe) and I've tried it a dozen times already:

**Exception Message: Could not connect to the remote computer ("XXXXX.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC. (type DeploymentDetailedException)**

I also tried to create a brand new website and published my project to that new website...but I receive the same error.

Since it's a shared server...there's no way for me to check if the '**Web Management Service**' is running! So...can somebody help me out here?

Comment: "Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer." - I doubt that is the problem anyway. Is there not any other major way to deploy? Direct upload for instance from the azure control panel?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use FTP publish. But then we have to do everything manually that our build-server is doing automatically.

Comment: Just stand up another website instance if the problem persists and republish your site there and update DNS to point to the new host.

Comment: What REALLY frustrates me is that Microsoft shows "All good! Everything is running great." on their Azure Status website. And they leave all of their clients (us) with the sh*t that they've caused...

Comment: Thanks, Simon...but I've created several website instances...on several location in the world. But they all have the same problem. Are you able to deploy to a website from Visual Studio?